# VS2010 + IE8 Debugging woes - Element not found

Tags: visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer-8

I am having great difficulty trying to debug with vs2010 and IE8, though I think the problem is more IE8 specific.
When starting a debug session 9 times out of 10 I will have the following problem.
IE tab says connecting.. - then after a 5 second wait I will get an error in VS saying element not found.
Even when I click ok to dismiss the error, the IE window still shows connecting... 
I will then have to kill the IE process to be able to close IE to try again.
Sometimes however I am lucky and it starts. But the whole thing is so random I have no clue where to start. One thing I have noticed is that I always have 2 IE processes started even though there is only one window open. One has a small footprint of 100k, I presume it is some kind of helper.

I am using a static port with the built in WebDev server.

If anyone has had similar problems please let me know how you resolved it. Its driving me nuts!
thanks

Comment: Have you tried other browsers? (at least just to verify the server is working)

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution?  I installed IE8 on XP SP3 and have the same issue.  No answers from this page helped, and despite the good intentions of suggesting  alternatives, nothing compares to debugging server-side code along with JavaScript in VS2010 with IE.  There simply is no adequate substitute.  This is a huge drag.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a restored tab issue. Go to **Internet Options** (ALT, T, O), go to the **"Advanced" tab**, then the **"Browsing" section** and ***uncheck* the "Enable Automatic Crash Recovery"** box.

You might also want to try **adding "localhost" as a trusted site** or (worse:) turning off "Protected Mode" for all the zones in the "Security" tab (at least for debugging).

If that doesn't solve it it may be *an inaccessible port*.

Turn off any software firewalls, ***check* netstat -a** in command prompt to make sure the necessary port is listening. If it does list the port as listening, the only thing I can think of that would have this effect would be the hosts file in the directory %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\ . Set "127.0.0.1       localhost" to be uncommented.

If the port is not listed as listening, it's a VS or service issue. [This VS 2005 page should cover any related causes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwesw3ee%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I take a different approach.  I will always launch the application and then use VS to attach to the problem.  Generally the steps work like this:

1. Set up the application to run in IIS.
2. Launch VS as Administrator or with Administrator rights.  If you do not do this step, VS will let you know.
3. Navigate to just before the problem.
4. In VS Go to Debug -> Attach to Process or use the hotkey CTRL+ALT+P
5. If the problem is in server-side code, then attack to w3wp.exe (verify you are connecting to the correct w3wp.exe you may have multiple, due to Classic/Pipeline) OR Attach to the instance of IE with the Title set to your webpages title.
6. If attached to the server, then VS will automatically break on error.  If attached to IE, ensure that you set a breakpoint at the correct position in VS.

Regardless, debugging IE using VS has always been a dicey thing.  IE8's built in debugger is usually up to the task.

An added benefit of using this method, is that it is faster to debug complicated web applications, as you can usually leave the web app open *near the problem spot* while you rebuild the site.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a clue on multiple running IE processes: if you start IE8 you'll get one host process and one worker process. When looking in the processes list in the Attach Process window in VS the host will show the title of the page while the worker will have no title. You want to attach to the worker process (the one with no title). This can be confusing so in general avoid multiple tabs when debugging so you always have two processes running.

Does the IE tab only stall with "Connecting..." when debugger is attached or otherwise as well? You haven't said anything about any breakpoints that might be active and if this might contribute to process not going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the stack trace in Visual Studio to see what is failing in the Javascript? What element is not found and where is it coming from?  What is expected?

I have had similar issues in the past and it can sometimes just be the result of bad javascript.  Use the stack trace tab in your debugger to see what element is failing.  If you are able to corrolate the element to an object in the DOM or better yet your code, you can narrow down where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I'd debug this in Chrome.  The built-in developer tools for debugging JavaScript are fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with IE8's LCIE (Loosely Coupled Internet Explorer) process model. IE8 introduced the (poorly thought out) idea of running new IE processes, as you open new browser tabs. You start off with two iexplore.exe instances in task manager, and these rapidly multiply to 8, 12 16 processes, etc, each grabbing huge amounts of memory and resources. VS2010 handles LCIE very badly, with various and numerous problems. Best practice is to disable LCIE:

1. Start->Run
2. Type regedit
3. Navigate to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main
4. Add a REG_DWORD key called TabProcGrowth
5. Set it to 0 (zero)
6. Close down all instances of IE.
7. Close down your VS2010 session.
8. Try again.

Even if this doesn't fix your problem, it will fix all sorts of other issues. TBH I don't see how anyone can debug VS2010 + IE without disabling LSIE.